# printing a decimal value to console

Tags: assembly, intel

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I am just not getting what exactly I am doing wrong :D

I am trying to convert a decimal to a string in assembler using AT&T Syntax on an Ubuntu machine (not sure if thats important lol)

Anyway, here is my code:

```
.code32     #use 32bit

.section .data

str:    .ascii  "Hello world!\n"
    strlen = . - str

.section .text

.global _start

_start:
    movl    $4, %eax        #4 = sys_write
    movl    $1, %ebx        #1 = console
    movl    $str, %ecx      #address of string to print
    movl    $strlen, %edx   #length of string
    int     $0x80           #sys_call

    movl    $1337, %eax #move some random number to eax
    xorl    %esi, %esi     #clear esi

loop:
    movl    $0, %edx
    movl    $10, %ebx
    divl    %ebx           #divide our number by 10... result will be in eax, remainder in edx
    addl    $48, %edx       #add 48 (ascii for '0') to convert our number to ascii
    pushl   %edx           #push ascii of our number onto stack
    addl    $1, %esi        #counter++
    cmpl    $0, %eax        #if result of division is 0, we are done
    jz      next
    jmp     loop

next:
    cmpl    $0, %esi        #if counter is 0, we are done
    jz      exit
    subl    $1, %esi        #counter--
    movl    $4, %eax        #4 = syswrite
    movl    $1, %ebx        #1 = console
    movl    %esp, %ecx     #address of highest byte on stack (the last number we pushed here)
    movl    $1, %edx        #is number 0-9, so only one char needs to be printed
    int     $0x80           #syscall
    addl    $4, esp     #move stackpointer to next byte
    jmp     next

exit:                      #clean exit
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    $0, %ebx
    int     $0x80
```

Now the problem is that this doesn't print my number :(
Printing the string "Hello world!\n" works fine and all registers are also correctly set... I've tried debugging this with gdb, checking eax, ebx, ecx, edx, and the actual value of esp at the end of the 'next' loop with the following results:
eax is always 4 (correct, just like in the Hello print)
ebx is always 1 (correct, just like in the Hello print)
ecx is always some negative number around -8000 (I assume that this is where my stack is at)
edx is always 1 (correct, just want one char printed)
the value of esp is: 49, 51, 51, 55 ... which corresponds to ascii: 1, 3, 3, 7 (which is correct, this should be printed)

So basically, all registers are set correctly (except maybe ecx, I'm not completely sure about that one, but pretty sure :D), but the syscall does nothing :(

We haven't learned how to create a new string somewhere to save my chars to, so that's why I'm just saving them on the stack, so please don't flame me for that :D

Its an exercise for college, so I cant use any calls to external functions.

Comment: Works fine here after changing `addl $4, esp` to `addl $4, %esp`.

Comment: Hm, I did indeed forget the % before that, but it doesn't fix it for me... The only output I get is "Hello world!", the number is never printed

Comment: Did you look at the very left end of your prompt? There is no linefeed at the end of the decimal output.

Comment: Try `as --32 test.s -o test.o` and `ld -m elf_i386 test.o`. Run it with `./a.out`.

Comment: Yea I did look the very left end of my prompt :D...
As I was debugging this, I went through it step by step, and there was no output either... and there I would have noticed as the gdb prompt is only "(gdb)" and a single char in front of that is still very noticable haha

Comment: Tried it with --32 (although this probably does nothing, as I already have .code32 as my first line) and -m elf_i386, but its still the same... Hello World! is printed fine, the number isnt -.-

Comment: I have to agree with @user2336377 -- it works for me once I add the missing `%`.  It works on the command line and it works in gdb (the missing newline makes it look odd, but the output is there).  What is your command line for compilation?  I used `gcc -g -nostdlib -o test test.S`.  Then run with `./test` or `gdb ./test`.

Comment: Using the compilation command from Tony does NOT work for me... only "Hello world!" is printed, no number. So I tried the command @rkhb again and it works now lol, no idea why, but it did not work yesterday... Anyway, thanks for all your help!